# how to updated the keywords from database

Tags: php, sql, html, database

hi i have stored 1000 keywords in my database . if i search any keyword(with in my database) my site title must come Like a AIRPORT NETWORKS this title i want . this is for search engine box. how can i do with sql queries i used that below query for displayed my site title.

```
$ConvertedResultArray = explode('<div id="resultsDiv">', $ConvertedResult);
$V1 = $ConvertedResultArray[0];
$V2 = $ConvertedResultArray[1];
$SponsoredContent = '';
if(strtolower($SearchQuery) == 'taxi')
{
$SponsoredContent = '<br />AIRPORTS<br />NETWORKS';
}
$ConvertedResult = "$V1$SponsoredContent$V2";
```

i have a only one table named `keywords`

if i entered that key "taxi" in search box That title comes infront of the page AIRPORTNETWORKS as like that if i entered in the whole 1000 words which it is stored in database it must be come .

how can i do that what sql query i have to use.is it possible. please help me if any one have an idea  thanks in advance

Comment: Code and question ar not really clear, sorry...What are you trying to achieve and what do you get instead?

Comment: i have a search box in my site if i give any key words in this search box that title should be displayed first i have stored more than 1000 keywords in my db need sql query.sorry if my question is unclear @damien

Comment: Could you please try to be more exact in your wording, it is not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this not the answer, but here is something to get you started

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Keywords
    WHERE Name LIKE "%AIRPORT%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX for that. I guess you are speaking about auto complete. if is tat you are talking about do the following steps.
  1. use the query given by PerformanceDBA
2. update the textbox value with the first row of query result by triggering textbox onkeyup() event.

If this is not what you want please rephrase your question so tat others can understand..